# Error running multi-level interclass correlation

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to run `mult.icc` to calculate multiple ICC's from a dataset. Data has group ID column, and 9 variables. All variables are numeric. I have run the following:

```
mult.icc(data[,c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9")],
         grpid=data$GroupID)
```

Sourced from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/multilevel/versions/2.6/topics/mult.icc

And received an error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~DV + grpid, data = , :   invalid type (list) for variable 'DV'

I have attached sample data.

[image]

There is very little information available online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can reproduce if the data is a tibble ; using the example in your link `mult.icc(dplyr::as_tibble(bh1996[,c("HRS","LEAD","COHES")]),grpid=bh1996$GRP)` gives the same error. If your data is a non-standard type try changing your data to a `data.frame`